# oauth2.0: 403 when I visit /oauth/authorize

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm new to Spring security oauth2.0, I am confused why I got 403 when I visit /oauth/authorize.
I add oauth dependency in my pom.xml like this:

```
<!-- SpringBoot Security dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

After that, I have two config files. one is WebSecurityConfig.java for Spring security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
package com.byhuang.config;

import com.byhuang.filter.TokenFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenFilter tokenFilter;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/login", "/oauth/*").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(tokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

The other one is AuthorizationServerConfig.java extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
package com.byhuang.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.AuthorizationCodeServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AuthorizationServerTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("c1")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .scopes("all")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "password")
                .autoApprove(false)
                .redirectUris("www.baidu.com");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices)
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.POST);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll")
                .checkTokenAccess("permitAll")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        defaultTokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(7200);
        defaultTokenServices.setRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(259200);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

I have added anonymous for any request like /oauth/* in WebSecurityConfig.java, so I started the application and visited http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?client_id=c1&response_type=code&scope=all&redirect_uri=www.baidu.com but it failed and got 403 error.
I'm not sure if this is related to my TokenFilter.java, I think it doesn't matter because the request doesn't carry the token.

```
package com.byhuang.filter;

import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.byhuang.LoginDTO;
import com.byhuang.utils.JWTUtils;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class TokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = request.getHeader("token");
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(token)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        Claims claims = JWTUtils.parseToken(token);
        String username = (String) claims.get("username");
        String userString = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(username);
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(userString)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("尚未登录！");
        }
        LoginDTO user = JSON.parseObject(userString, LoginDTO.class);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, null);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The only other relevant ones are the classes that define beans：

```
package com.byhuang.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.AuthorizationCodeServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * @author huangbingyi
 * @version 1.0
 * @date 2023/6/18 18:35
 * @description TODO
 */
@Configuration
public class GlobalBeanConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices();
    }

}
```

I've tried almost every solution I could find but it still doesn't work. Is there something I've overlooked?

Comment: Why using so old libs? Why not using Spring Boot?

Comment: oh, thanks. can you show me the new libs dependency? I've searched spring boot oauth dependency in the maven repo, but it didn't show the new libs.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html